# Convert Typed Text in ASP.NET Designer to a Label

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

How can I convert text that I type manually into the VS ASP.NET Designer into a Label control?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to source view, you can highlight the text you want to turn into a label, and then right click it and select "Insert Snippet".  Click ASP.Net and then click Label.